# Pass instance as function argument

Tags: python, oop, function, instance

I wrote a nice little app that gets Yahoo weather info and posts it to Twitter. It worked flawlessly and now I want to rearrange the code into differently named files so it makes more sense. And that's when I hit some issues.

Previously, I had a `Class` in `libtweather.py`. It was my `account`. It allowed me to do `accountName.parseFeed()` and I'd get as output the parsed Yahoo weather. *(`__ini__` took the weather URL, twitter username and password as args)*

This was accessed from my main script which created instances of the `Class` like this:
`exec '%s = lw.twitterWeather("%s", "%s", "%s")' % (item[0], item[1], item[2], item[3])`
It kept a list of all account names in a list which was passed as argument to the other functions.

Another function `getWeather` got weather by doing:

```
def getWeather(accountList): #account names passed as a list of strings
    for item in accountList:
        print item, ': ',
        item = eval(item)       
        print item.parseFeed(), '\n
```

I've decided now to move the `getWeather` function to the same file as the `Class` but the line `item = eval(item)`'s giving me problems because there are no instances created in that file. All of them are in the main script.

Now my question: Is there some way I could give those instances as arguments to the function? Or must I put the function into the `Class`? Even if I did that, I'd still need to do the `item.parseFeed()` for multiple items in the list so I'd still need the `item = eval(item)`, no?

Thanks in advance. My app's a tad bit to post here in entirety, but I'll post more code if needed to understand better.

**Update:** I ended up running my `libtweather.py` to create instances when it's imported so that the functions inside it can access them (added the instance generating code at the bottom of the script). I'm sure there's a better way but it works for me currently and I'm OK with that.

Comment: Are there any specific reasons why you chose to use `exec` for making instances of the class?

Comment: None whatsoever. Except that it was the first way I came across on Google. I know I could use either `globals()`, `vars()`, or `locals()`. I'm looking at them now to see which one I'm going to use.

Comment: If you ever find yourself needing to use `eval` or `exec`, don't. do something else instead. don't ever use them. Unless you need to of course, that's why they're there but before you know that you __need__ them, you have to know that there is __no other good way__ to do what you want. This is almost never the case.

Comment: Thanks, I'll be looking at different methods. The `exec` and `eval` were the only things I knew when I started learning Python. I'm still learning..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be using an explicit dict for storing these items. `eval`, `exec`, `globals`, `locals`, and `vars` are all horribly silly ways to do this poorly. Remember from the Zen of Python: "explicit is better than implicit."

```
feeds = {}
for item in whatever:
    feeds[item[0]] = lw.twitterWeather(*item[1:])

def getWeather(feeds, accountList):
    for item in accountList:
        print '%s: %s' % (item, feeds[item].parseFeed())
```

Comment: I never thought of a dict. This app was how I started learning Python and I only recently started realizing the amazingness of dicts. 
But if I have `getWeather` defined in the same file as the Class and I generate the instances in my main script (separate from Class file), can I pass this dict as argument to my function and have instances point at the right place (inside the Class file, the function can't have a `lw.whatever` because the `lw` never gets imported.) And thanks for the `*item[1:]`; didn't know you could do that. *Sorry but I'm still kind of new to all this :P*

Comment: So I finally changed this. It didn't take as much changing to get my functions to use a dict instead of what I had before. 

Although I'm not using the same organization as my initial question (I'm creating instances inside my libtweather.py, not in main script), I tried out passing the dict to the `getWeather` function inside the `libtweather.py` from my main script and it worked. the instances were accepted without errors. So answer accepted. Thanks!